# Tools for degrading my network connection?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, throttling

I've written some applications than heavily use network, and I would like to test it over a slow network. I'm looking for a tool to simulate these kind of connections.

I'm only interested in Windows tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network tools that simulate slow network connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used [Traffic Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html) on my XP dev box at work.  It seems to handle any connection (not just HTTP).  It wasn't perfect, but worked well enough for the tests I was doing.  If you're on Windows maybe it'll do enough for you.

Comment: Solution doesn't work with Windows 7

Answer (score 6):

Try [dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/ip_dummynet/). 
You will find lots of resources on the web, including this [tutorial](http://www.scalabledesign.com/articles/dummynet.html).

Comment: @JL dummynet now supports Windows

Comment: dummynet windows-binaries are defunct ... its built against cygwin hence wont even start if you dont have a fully configured cygwin-framework on your machine. Its basically useless.

Answer (score 6):

Throughput, latency, jitter, and packet loss can all impact user experience.  Several software solutions that run on a host (or VM) allow these "levers" to be pulled.

Last time I researched I found a few possibilities:

[Wanem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/)

[dummyet (link1)](http://groups.google.ca/group/comp.unix.programmer/msg/a152e2be5dc05fa5)
[dummynet (link2)](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/ip_dummynet/)

[nistnet](http://snad.ncsl.nist.gov/itg/nistnet/)

[shunra (link1)](http://www.shunra.com/download.aspx)
[shunra (link2)](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2008/04/13/simulating-high-latency-and-low-bandwidth-for-database-connectivity-testing.aspx)

[tmnetsim](http://tmurgent.com/Tools.aspx)
[tmnetsim](http://www.msterminalservices.org/articles/How-To-Simulate-WAN-Area-Connection-Test-Lab-Free.html)

[Cisco WAN-Bridge (CCO Login Required)](http://www.cisco.com/cgi-bin/Software/Tablebuild/doftp.pl?ftpfile=/cisco/stornet/fe-511/util/wan-bridge-1.07.iso)

If you want something client based maybe try shunra, and if you want something in the infrastructure wanem is pretty easy since their is a VMWare appliance available.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of network traffic? If it's HTTP this will work for you:

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 3):

How about [this tool](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Network-Testing/Network-Traffic-Generator.shtml) (network Traffic Generator) ?

Answer (score 2):

[Clumsy](http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/) seems to be a promising new tools for testing with degraded network performance.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. dummynet works only in FreeBSD, it's actually built into the kernel.

What I did when I used it was grab an older PC nobody used anymore and install the [FreeBSD distribution](http://www.freebsd.org/releases/7.0R/announce.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a(nother) web proxy that can be used to degrade your connection.

Answer (score 0):

Dummynet is the way to go, especially if you want to simulate complex scenarios such as ADSL connections (asymmetric uplink and downlink), "Slow connection" (long latency), lossy links, etc. As Christian said, you can find some spare old PCs and install FreeBSD. You can also use VMware but I wouldn't recommand that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do HTTP throttling [Charles Web Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is absolutely great for this. Please do have a look at it.