# Bandwidth throttling for Apache<2.2 on Windows (mod_throttle?)

Tags: windows, apache, bandwidth, throttling

Does anyone know of a windows build of mod_throttle for Apache 2.2 or lower?

Or perhaps another means by which to throttle bandwidth. I need to throttle as low as 64k for a local speed test demonstration

Preferably Apache rather than a browser plug-in too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mod_throttle, but I just tried [Traffic Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html), it went as low as 33K (it might be able to go lower).  I actually "found" the answer to your problem in another stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107/tool-for-degrading-my-network-connection).  I've needed a tool like this in the past but had never found a good one (but this one looks good).  One last note, I didn't want to mess with my network stack on my dev machine, so I used a [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) Win XP image (I use these for testing various versions of IE).

Answer (score 0):

Yo may try mod_bandwith as explained [here](http://www.securityhacking.info/2010/01/limit-download-speed-in-apache-2-2-windows/).