# how to throttle akamai stream

Tags: flash, video, streaming, akamai

i'm testing a flash site with Charles Proxy. It doesn't appear to be throttling the video stream from Akamai that we're using. Is there a way to simulate how the stream will work on a slow connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charles is just a web proxy, so it won't throttle traffic that doesn't go through your HTTP proxy (like streaming flash video does, over port 1935). Instead you need another application that can throttle all traffic.

This other post may help:
[Tools for degrading my network connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107/tool-for-degrading-my-network-connection)

Answer (score 0):

You can also force the connection to rtmpt instead of rtmp which will force it to tunnel over port 80 and via Charles.