# delay the process time in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing the progress bar in ajax, jquery with php. I need to delay the uploading process file the file is uploaded. Here is my code.

```
uploadProgress : function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        $("#progressbar").width(percentComplete + '%');     
        $("#percent").html(percentComplete + '%');
        if (percentComplete > 50) {
            $("#message").html("<font color='red'>File Upload is in progress .. </font>");
        }
        },
```

how can i delay the progress bar loading to show the completed percentage? or is there any other solution?

Comment: Isn't it nice if upload is so fast that you can't see the progress bar? I would choose to display a (different) message when uploading is complete, and let the upload itself run as fast as possible.

Comment: With @GolezTrol 's comment, it is also worth to note that the upload will actually take much more time in a remote server. You must be using your own computer right?

Comment: Yes.. Actually I'm asking for a test process.. Weather it is start from 1 to 100 or just ends with 100..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing purposes you can use network throttling in Chrome developer tools (in [mobile device emulator mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)). Or any of network throttling tools discussed for example in [this offtopic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107/tools-for-degrading-my-network-connection).

UPD: [another topic about network throttling](https://superuser.com/questions/330501/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-or-limit-the-bandwidth-that-firefox-can-us).