# Limit TCP speed and throughput for debugging

Tags: java, c#, sockets, debugging, tcp

I'm developing a network application.
Until now I wrote a simple server (java) and a simple client (C#).
They are communicating over tcp sockets.
Both are running on my computer. Therefor communication is obviously very fast and throughput is high.
For debugging I want a tool that is capable to limit the connection speed and allows me to drop packages on the tcp layer.
I hope that in this way I could test my setup in a more realistic way.

Comment: If you can't bring Mohammad to the mountain bring the mountain to Mohammad.  There is no method to slow down tcp so I would add a delay after the Write method so packets are sent are not sent continuously.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107/tools-for-degrading-my-network-connection

Comment: @jdweng OP is interested in throttling at the TCP layer. To simulate possible real network behaviors. Having delays at the application does not help the cause.

Comment: I though they just need time to process input and drop packages because the data was arriving faster than they could process.